# What's the difference between opening a folder using file://C:\Folder against C:\Folder?

Tags: windows, shell-extensions

This question is mostly related to namespace extensions, but maybe if i understand the root, i can see what i'm doing wrong.

i've set a junction point to my namespace extension (using Desktop.ini file).
eventually, the folders are not real, and they are virtual.

the junction point is at **C:\VirtualFolder**, and the root namespace folder is **NamespaceRoot**

when i perform via start...run:

```
C:\VirtualFolder\NamespaceRoot\Folder
```

i get an error "Location is not available" C:\VirtualFolder\ refers to a location that is unavailable....

when i do this:

```
file://C:\VirtualFolder\NamespaceRoot\Folder
```

everything works, my virtual folder opens.

anyone can shed a light for this behavior?

thanks.

Comment: When you work with file:// system uses protocol handler associated with file: protocol. And it looks like protocol handler can process namespace extensions.

Comment: is there any technical explanation why?

Comment: In broad terms, it's the difference between using a Shell API function (which understands namespace extensions) and a generic Win32 API function such as CreateFile or CreateProcess (which doesn't).  Why the Run dialog in particular is behaving this way is less obvious, perhaps for compatibility with the command line.

Comment: @HarryJohnston so if im using junction points, you just cant go to your folder via run command in any way? You have to use the file protocol? No other better workaround?

Comment: I don't know.  But I think usually virtual folders either don't contain virtual subdirectories (like the Fonts folder) or the virtual folder structure is echoed by the real directory structure.  So try creating real directories for NamespaceRoot and Folder and see if that helps.  Once the folder is open, the virtual *files* should still be shown, I think.

Comment: I tried.. It opens the real folder, and its too dirty solution if it would work

Comment: @HarryJohnston btw Harry, i think your answer is the most logical one. if you're sure, just post it as an answer and i'll accept it.

Comment: I'm hoping someone with familiarity with shell namespace extensions will answer. :-)  Did you remember to put `desktop.ini` files in each of the subdirectories?

Comment: @harryjohnston no need, only the root should have the desktop.ini, then after running the attrib command it shows my extension

Comment: That's a nice theory, but you've tried it and it didn't work.  Granted, I don't know whether putting `desktop.ini` files in the subdirectories will work either, but it seems like a sensible thing to try.

Comment: I dont want to create all real folders. Besides, which clsid will i put there? Only the namespace root which will cause all subdirectories to point on the root. So it doesnt look viable. Ill test it anyway tomorrow and see if this somehow fixes the issue as it means that the folders will indeed exist (but not the files)